# How to add SSL certificate for https request while logging in iphone

Tags: ios

I have gone through all the related posts regarding this SSL certificate issue.
I dont want to bypass it by using the below methods.

```
 -(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
  return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
      [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

  [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

And also I dont want to add the certificate by manual in the iphone and in simulator.

Actually I need a pop up messge should indicate the user that the certificate for this server is invalid and do you need to add this certificate for your process?.... this kind of message needs to be asked to the user whenever finds some https request.....

Is there any example or how to do?....